# XML is showing OLD API UI ANDroid

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

I am developing an app and using spinners(Using **eclipse**). I am using **Fragments** and also using **support-v4 library.** I have set **MinSdkVersion** to **8** for backword compativility.

The problem is, in XML, when I drag and drop **spinners**, it is showing me the old UI for spinner which was there in API 8 or 9 and designing UI is becoming almost impossible.
(However in my Phone, it is showing the latest UI for Spinner, but I can't design it well in XML - eclipse.)

Also attaching the **URL of snapshot** (as I don't have enough reputation to post and image) of the XML view within the eclipse.

**Link to Image :**  http://tinyurl.com/ErrorInUI

I tried changing MinSdkVersion to 17. It didn't work.

Comment: Der Golem is right. One little note: if you want to use holo styles on your elements on pre-ICS versions you should think about using https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere lib

Answer (score 1):

In your XML Graphical editor, you can **change** the appearance by selecting the rendering style in the API Level dropdown (there's the current API Level number with an arrow, near the little green robot):

[image]

Comment: I have tried to set it to 11 but, did't make any change.

I will try further increasing the MinSdkVersion.